# Negate having to Press Enter twice on PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a PowerShell script daily through task scheduler, however the script will not run. When I enter the code below manually into PowerShell (as an administrator), it makes me press enter twice. I believe since i have to press enter twice is the reason it will not run through the task scheduler.

Is there a way to adjust my code to get this to work with the task scheduler?

I am running Windows 2012 R2 and Version 5.1 of PowerShell.

Please note that i ran the exact same script on my computer, which is Windows 10 and running version 5.1 of PowerShell, and it worked the correct way (only had to press enter once)

I expect to only press enter once to run my PowerShell script, but the actual output from the first time i press enter brings another line with just ">>" and then i press enter the second time and the script executes.

Powershell Script:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
   Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

 # Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = ""
    UserName = ""
    Password = ""
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = ""
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Transfer files
    $session.PutFiles("", "").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: What is the last run result when you run it via the task scheduler? How are you running it via the task scheduler?

Comment: That code does not request any key press. If your are asked for a key press, it has nothing to do with the code you have posted. --- Show us some screenshots. + What is the minimal code that still asks for a keypress?

Answer (score 0):

If a script requires user interaction, then it really should not be a scheduled task.

If you write a script that requires confirmation, then you need to look using -Confirm parameter.

See [Are you sure? Using the -WhatIf and -Confirm parameters in PowerShel](https://discoposse.com/2012/01/02/are-you-sure-using-the-whatif-and-confirm-parameter-in-powershell/)

Remove-MailContact -Identity “$sourceEmail” -Confirm:$Y -WhatIf

The cmdlet or code you write has to support it. For code you write, that means using [advanced functions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-advanced-functions-in-powershell/).

[How to write a PowerShell function to use Confirm, Verbose and WhatIf](https://sqldbawithabeard.com/2018/01/25/how-to-write-a-powershell-function-to-use-confirm-verbose-and-whatif/)

```
function Set-FileContent 
{
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Content,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateScript( {Test-Path $_ })]
        [string]$File
    )

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$File" , "Adding $Content to ")) 
    {
        Set-Content -Path $File -Value $Content
    }
}
```

See also [ConfirmPreference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/confirmpreference)